# .NET MVC view returning object name rather than specific object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm returning a list of lists to an MVC view, displayed as a set of tables. I'm using nested for loops to try to return the values within each list.

The tables are returning to the view with the expected number of rows in each, but instead of values in each of the rows, they are returning the names of their parameters, rather than the actual value of each parameter.

The code in my view is currently:

```
@if (Model.Report != null)
        {
            for(var row = 0; row < Model.Report.Count(); row++)
            {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h4>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.Report[row].ReportData[row].ReportingGroup)</h4></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-header">
                        <td style="text-align: center">Name</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">Area</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">Message</td>
                    </tr>

                    @for (var listing = 0; listing < Model.Report[row].ReportData.Count(); listing++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center">@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Report[row].ReportData[listing].Name)</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center">@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Report[row].ReportData[listing].Area)</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center">@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Report[row].ReportData[listing].Message)</td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            }
       }
```

Rather than the actual values of the parameters returning to each row in the view, I'm returning the parameter names("Name", "Area", and "Message") to each. I am wondering where I've gone wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LabelFor` displays a label for the property you pass it.  Without further attributes, that's just the property name.

You just want to print the value itself:

```
@Model.Report[row].ReportData[listing].Message
```

You should replace your `for` loop with a `foreach` so you don't need to do all that.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `LabelFor` to `DisplayFor` or `TextBoxFor` in your for loop.